# Is there an easy way to know which contact changed while using ContentObserver for android contacts?

Tags: android, contacts, contentobserver

I store some contacts in my app and want to know if any one of them is edited by user through the contact app. So I register a contentObserver for this. The 'onChange()' method for the contentObserver doesn't provide anything other than 'selfChange' boolean parameter. So is there any way I can find which contact changed other that looping through every contact and comparing the fields for changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the same question that I have [posed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996921/how-do-i-make-my-android-contentobserver-for-contactscontract-detect-a-added-upd) and so far, it does not appear there is a meaningful way other than looping through.

Comment: Yeah too bad. I researched quite a bit too and turned out there is no way of knowing it easily :(